# Would my prayers be invalid if I read a letter of durood shareef wrong unintentionally?

Tags: sunnah

Had my prayers been valid if I had been reading a letter of durood shareef wrong unintentionally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes your prayer is still valid since durood shareef is not part of the "Fard" or obligation of the prayer.

The Prophet was quoted to have said that a mistakes and forgetfulness will not count against my people.